# Import file CSV on odoo 8 using method many2one

Tags: python, csv, import, odoo-8

I'm starting learning about odoo and i have problem when i tried to import CSV file. The problem is show up like this :

```
Cannot execute name_search, no _rec_name defined on prov.model
```

I was create the code like this :

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class Practice(models.Model):
    _name = 'practice.practice'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    prov = fields.Many2one(
        'prov.model',
        'name_prov',
        # string='Provinc',
    )

class Provinc(models.Model):
    _name = 'prov.model'

    name_prov = fields.Char(
        string='Provinc',
    )
```

I don't know what i have to do, i tried to edit my code but it's still not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you click on many2one dropdown name_search method calls which searches for "name" field in model to display data in dropdown

Since you don't have "name" field and didn't specified _rec_name either so Odoo is not able to identify field you want to display in many2one dropdown and gives error.

you need to mention name_prov field in _rec_name to tell odoo that this is the name field that which is going to be display in many2one dropdown.

Make this changes.

```
class Provinc(models.Model):
    _name = 'prov.model'
    _rec_name ='name_prov'     #this tells odoo use this field for m2o field

    name_prov = fields.Char(string='Provinc')
```

> And correct  Many2one field definition # doesn't need specify inverse_name like One2many
>
> prov = fields.Many2one('prov.model')

Comment: Now i got new error, the error is 

DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Comment: oh yes!! you don't need to specify any inverse_name in Many2one field declaration #Added in  answer check it.

Comment: I'm sorry But it's still error. the error is :

No matching record found for name " " in field " " at row 2

Comment: provide your full Traceback!!

Comment: That's all my traceback

Comment: nope!! i want traceback you are getting in console/terminal

Comment: '
2017-05-18 07:20:39,255 23763 INFO 8_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2017 07:20:39] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/base_import.import/parse_preview HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2017-05-18 07:20:46,034 23763 INFO 8_odoo openerp.addons.base_import.models: importing 19 rows...
2017-05-18 07:20:46,731 23763 INFO 8_odoo openerp.addons.base_import.models: done
'

Comment: This is because you inherited  'res.partner'  in "Practice"  and that model must have some required data that you don't have in  csv file you are importing...